# Tableau: sum of sales falls in set date

Tags: date, sum, tableau-api

would like to seek your expertise on this calculation.

sum of sales should automatically fall in ND dates if queue date and ND is matched, workbook attached for reference here: https://community.tableau.com/thread/268194

ND

April 1, 2018 = 5617

April 2, 2018 = 0

April 3, 2018 = 0

April 4, 2018 = 0

April 5, 2018 = 0

April 6, 2018 = 0

April 7, 2018 = 0

April 8, 2018 = 0

April 9, 2018 = 4318

April 10, 2018 = 0

April 11, 2018 = 0

April 12, 2018 = 0

April 13, 2018 = 0

April 14, 2018 = 0

April 15, 2018 = 0

April 16, 2018 = 0

April 17, 2018 = 0

April 18, 2018 = 0

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The question should be self-contained (not dependent on some off site file in a Tableau unique format). Plus it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Explain more about the requirement